# How does modern disk image software make accurate images of drives in use?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

In the old days, if I wanted to image a drive in Windows, in it needed to be unmounted.  Which for the system drive usually meant using a boot disk or rebooting into a "stub" that loaded before Windows completed loading to do the copy.  Which makes a lot of sense, since they were essentially just copying sector-by-sector and couldn't detect if a previously copied sector was changed by the filesystem.

Modern imaging software doesn't seem to require this, and will happily make an image of a drive in use.  Even the Windows system drive.

How does it do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Windows XP there is the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service) which can show a "point in time" consistent backup capable view of a system or disk that is in use without it needing to be unmounted first. It appears to have been variously enhanced and and used by other applications as a backup service.

> Backing up and restoring critical business data can be very complex due to the following issues:
>
> - The data usually needs to be backed up while the applications that produce the data are still running. This means that some of the data files might be open or they might be in an inconsistent state.
> - If the data set is large, it can be difficult to back up all of it at one time.
>
> ...
>
> VSS coordinates the actions that are required to create a consistent shadow copy (also known as a snapshot or a point-in-time copy) of the data that is to be backed up.
>
> ...
>
> #### System provider
>
> One shadow copy provider, the system provider, is supplied in the Windows operating system. Although a default provider is supplied in Windows, other vendors are free to supply implementations that are optimized for their storage hardware and software applications.
>
> To maintain the "point-in-time" view of a volume that is contained in a shadow copy, the system provider uses a copy-on-write technique. Copies of the blocks on volume that have been modified since the beginning of the shadow copy creation are stored in a shadow copy storage area.

That page continues on

> #### What is the difference between a shadow copy and a backup?
>
> In the case of a hard disk drive backup, the shadow copy created is also the backup. Data can be copied off the shadow copy for a restore or the shadow copy can be used for a fast recovery scenario—for example, LUN resynchronization or LUN swapping.
>
> When data is copied from the shadow copy to tape or other removable media, the content that is stored on the media constitutes the backup. The shadow copy itself can be deleted after the data is copied from it.

> #### When was Volume Shadow Copy Service introduced? On which Windows operating system versions is it available?
>
> VSS was introduced in Windows XP. It is available on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista®, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @r2d3: [There is.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/volume-shadow-copy-service-portal#run-time-requirements) You just can't make _persistent_ shadow copies with it (a deliberate restriction, not present in Server 2003), but you can make temporary ones (kept until the handle is released). Microsoft's own (well, Sysinternals') Disk2Vhd tool uses VSS and can image running XP system. I've even written my own backup program on WinXP that used VSS.  It might well be missing from XP Home, but it definitely existed in Pro.

Comment: @r2d3 I had originally written my answer as Windows 7 rather than XP, but changed it based on the page I linked. "Previous  versions" of files I'm absolutely certain was in XP and I remember using it, but I think the system was massively overhauled and improved in subsequent windows versions, to the point where it was also used with the built in Windows backup tool in Vista and Windows 7. The framework, if not the entire frontend, was there in XP.

Comment: If you use Macrium Reflect, you can observe the sequence of events, which *includes utilizing Volume Shadow Copy*. Alas, this is one advantage Windows has over Linux -- it would be useful to image mounted disks, beyond dd's capabilities.

Comment: @r2d3 xp is explicitly mentioned in that page "**When was Volume Shadow Copy Service introduced? On which Windows operating system versions is it available? VSS was introduced in Windows XP.** It is available on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista®, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Mokubai, after reading the beginning of the article I immediately stopped and missed any XP references. That intro backed my doubt upon my experience with Acronis True Image.
The beginning of the article state:
Applies to: Windows Server 2022, Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly Acronis was the first company whose product "True Image" was able to backup a running system.

They did so by installing a filter driver. They were basically hooking the Windows program code to write sectors in Windows XP.

This would allow them to keep track of all sectors that had already been copied during the backup process and where new sector write operations would have invalidated the data that had already been backed up.

This way they were able to create a real valid snapshot that took as long to take as the backup process was running.
The total backup time needed equals the sum of the backup time for the partition(s) and the time needed to backup the sectors that were written by the operating system during the backup process.

Obviously this type of backup would only work well if there was not too much write load on the partition(s) involved.

I personally would prefer the above-mentioned "stub" solution which essentially was a live linux with a graphical user interface that ressembled Windows XP.

Comment: Nope. I think it was PowerQuest's DriveImage.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I remember having read that information in the German computer journal c't.

Comment: Such an *excellent* magazine, have been subscribed to that for years in the past!