# Why do I have to clone a disk from live USB?

Tags: hard-drive, clonezilla, disk-cloning

Why do I have to clone a disk by running a live USB (with programs such as Clonezilla .iso) ?
I don't understand it, its just copying, why can't I do it while windows is running?
I would like to understand technically why...

Comment: You don't. I've used many programs that can clone a live system. Macrium Reflect for one... the only risk is that you have have program running while the clone is in progress that it may end up with older data on the cloned disk.

Comment: MRF8 will do a clone while booted, I use it all the time, its Free also>>>https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, and there are times when you don't need to do this.  Assuming you are talking about the common case of cloning a disk which is operational (eg cloning your current windows setup), the answer is this -

Cloning a disk takes a while. During this time the contents of the disk will very likely change, even if only due to background processes. This means that the file index (typically stored at the start if the disk) will be out of sync with the actual filesystem layout - which can cause corruption, instability and data loss.

I comment that cloning a disk is a block operation - ie the whole hard drive is treated like a single file - this is different to copying files within the OS because a block copy has no knowledge of the filesystem layout stored inside the block.

Comment: I see.. I thought it was a bit strange that cloning programs designed to run on running systems is uncommon.. Its good that I know why now..

Comment: I would like to ask one more further question, If I cloned the disk on an operational Windows with Macrium Reflect for example, and left my pc completely until its done, there would give me a perfect stable clone right?

Comment: You see I have a problem right now, and that is that windows is behaving strangely unresponsive, like ignoring 1/4 of my mouse clicks, I'm pulling my hair out because Ive eliminated all my possible causes.. I do not know what to do at the moment..

Comment: No, it would likely NOT give you a perfect clone.  Cloning requires that none of the bits on the disk change between the time you start the process and finish the process.   On a system with a read/write disk, the chances of this happening are very, very small - because of Windows may decide to write to swap, or write a log file, or do a background cleanup or flush a disk cache or another program might do something - even just browsing the web will create temporary files....  Also, if Windows is unresponsive and you bit-copy the disk, unless the old disk is failing you will copy the problem.

Comment: ok this is helpful.. thankfully my specific problem just got solved.. I probably had an important service disabled and I started enable several and restarted and its fixed..

Answer (score 2):

Please read the following thread as well:
**How does modern disk image software make accurate images of drives in use?**

[How does modern disk image software make accurate images of drives in use?](https://superuser.com/questions/1691250/how-does-modern-disk-image-software-make-accurate-images-of-drives-in-use/1691287#1691287)

Cloning offline media (using "live operating systems" on a USB stick p.e.) is more reliable than cloning.
Furthermore imagine cloning to a tape drive where you would need to add all intermediate changes of your operating system as well. Each write operation of the running operating sytem would extend the length of the clone on tape. Using a "live operating system" would prevent the clone on tape from being extended by write operations on the media in question.